# How to change a java key password?

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

I tried with this command:

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias key0
```

and I get this:

```
keytool error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: -keypasswd commands not supported if -storetype is PKCS12
```

however the output of:

```
keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.jks -v
```

is the following:

```
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: key0
Creation date: 21 Dec 2017
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at this https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228462/how-to-change-pkcs12-keystore-password-using-keytool&ved=0ahUKEwj7wu-d56LYAhVEUlAKHbw0C90QjjgIIzAA&usg=AOvVaw1FZsrOFwOjqOSXGAGvy64R

Comment: @JoSSte Yes but it doesn't work, if I try it I get: `keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`

Comment: Try [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org) for two reasons: 1. It has - unlike keytool - a reliable keystore type detection. 2. It can handle PKCS12 keystores with different passwords for store and key.